# Powershell creating folders and assigning security users

Tags: powershell

Goal of this function is to 1) copy a template folder, 2) rename that template folder, 3) assign folder security user.

The problems I'm having with my code are:

1) Does not rename copied folder. I only want to rename the parent folder and not the subfolders.

```
**Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ("Template" -f $ProjectName)} -Verbose**
```

2) I get an error for $TargetFolder.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)

```
Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
"
At C:\Users\ProjectFolderCreation_TEST.ps1:40 char:6
+      $TargetFolder.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
```

Below is my full code.

```
Function FolderCreation{ 
Param (
       # [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $region,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $env,
        #[Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $server,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $ProjectCode

        )


 $TemplatePath = "C:\Desktop\FunctionInputs\PRJ"

 $NetApp = "C:\Users\Desktop\FunctionOutputs\ProjectFolders\"+$env 

 $ProjectName = "$($ProjectCode)"

 $ProjectFolder = $NetApp+"\$ProjectName"
 #$ProjectFolder

 $AdminAccess = "domain\GP_"+$ProjectName+"_ADMIN_LCL"
 #$AdminAccess

 if(Test-Path -Path $TemplatePath) {
     Get-ChildItem $TemplatePath -Filter *Template* -Recurse |
           Copy-Item -Destination $NetApp -Recurse -Verbose |
           **Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ("Template" -f $ProjectName)} -Verbose**
        }


 if(Test-Path -Path $ProjectFolder){
     #get actual acl (access control list) entry 
     $TargetFolder = Get-Acl $ProjectFolder

     #configuring new acl
     $AdminAccess = "domain\GP_$ProjectName_ADMIN_LCL"
     $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($AdminAccess, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None","Allow")

     #setting new acl
     **$TargetFolder.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)** 
     $TargetFolder | Set-Acl "$ProjectFolder" -Verbose

     #check if new entry was added 
     Get-Acl "$ProjectFolder" | fl 
        }
else{
    Write-Host ( $ProjectFolder +" does not exists")
    }

}
FolderCreation
```

Comment: I would recommend stepping through your script using the debugger in the ISE.

Comment: I think this is a typo. `$TargerFolder` should be `$TargetFolder`, right?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I have, the code copies the Template folder and contents to its new location. However, it does not rename the file, which causes the Acl If loop to not run and print  `C:\Users\FunctionOutputs\ProjectFolders\Dev\ABC does not exists` . If I run the code in steps, I get the null error for $TargerFolder.SetAcessRule($AccessRule).

Comment: @techguy1029, yes! I didn't noticed that typo. I updated my question to reflect the new error.

Comment: `SetAccessRule` instead of `SetAcessRule`

Comment: @techguy1029, woah, thank you for catching that! Should be no more typos. Updated new error.

Comment: @jessgtrz Here is an article regarding [that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2771040/the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain)

Comment: @techguy1029, thank you! I'm new to ACL and AD, and I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936218/adding-an-active-directory-group-with-powershell). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here you literally do a recursive on all folders:

```
 if(Test-Path -Path $TemplatePath) {
     Get-ChildItem $TemplatePath -Filter *Template* -Recurse |
           Copy-Item -Destination $NetApp -Recurse -Verbose |
           **Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ("Template" -f $ProjectName)} -Verbose**
        }
```

Remove the line Rename-Item, What you have to do is create new parent directory with a new name and move all child folders to new directory, no need for rename.

You need admin privileges, run the code as admin and try again.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. My new code looks likes this                                                 `$TemplatePath = "C:\Users\PRJ\Template\*"                
 if(Test-Path -Path $TemplatePath) {
      $ProjectFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $NetApp\$($ProjectName) -Verbose
      Copy-Item -Path $TemplatePath -Destination $ProjectFolder -Recurse -Verbose 
          
        }`

Comment: great, was the ACL issue fixed by running as admin?

Comment: I just realized, that though my above code produces what I want ( copy the folder Template), I have no way to error handle that the folder Template is copy and not another folder. Is there a way to filter and copy only if the folder name is "Template" ...? Just thinking of how I can make a safe code

Comment: add a test function for the source. check count files in parent folder == 1 and confirm the folder name is template. if function returns true then copy otherwise print an error code. more about functions in powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6

Comment: thank you. I made a new question regarding [AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936218/adding-an-active-directory-group-with-powershell). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate another set of eyes. Thanks!