# Adding an Active Directory group with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a new group in the DomainLocal with Powershell but my code below is not working. I don't get an error, but nor does it create the group in the path given.

```
Function AD{
Param (
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $ProjectCode

        )

 #setting up Folder template path and name for folders
 $ProjectName = "$($ProjectCode)"

 $Folder = "C:\FunctionOutputs\ProjectFolders"
 $ProjectFolder = " $Folder\$($ProjectName)"


 #establishing AD group and member naming conventions
 $adminName = "AB_"+$ProjectName+"_CDE_ADMIN_LCL"
 $adminName

  #check that new $ProjectFolder exists to create "_ADMIN_LCL" group
 if(Test-Path -Path $ProjectFolder){

      New-ADGroup -Name $adminName  -GroupScope DomainLocal -DisplayName $adminName -Path "OU=Groups, OU=Test, OU=Ohio, OU=NA, DC=aws, DC=example, DC=com" -Verbose
      }
}
```

Comment: So that defines a function. How are you calling that function?

Comment: @Gabriel Luci  I put it in a function out of habit. And I've been calling it the way I call all functions. I will try it without a function

Comment: Why do you add a space character here: `$ProjectFolder = " $Folder\$($ProjectName)"` ?

Comment: @Theo Good catch. That's likely the problem right there. Even `Test-Path " C:\"` will return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting no output at all, that likely means that

```
Test-Path -Path $ProjectFolder
```

is returning `False`. That is, the project directory doesn't exist, so it doesn't even try to create the group. If you are calling this with a new project name that you have not previously created a directory for, then that's expected, since you're not creating the folder in this code.

If you would like to create the directory, you can use:

```
New-Item $ProjectFolder -ItemType Directory
```

Also, this is suspicious:

```
-Path "OU=Groups, OU=Test, OU=Ohio, OU=NA, DC=aws, DC=example, DC=com"
```

Distinguished names in AD don't have spaces after the commas. As-is, that would throw an exception.

Comment: sorry, the folder has been created. I have another script for that.  And in my complete code, I have an `else statement` if $ProjectFolder doesn't exist, which it does, so I'm guessing that's why no output?  So maybe the path. I will execute it with no spaces after the commas.

Comment: But your `New-ADGroup` line is not running. If it was, you'd see an error. See the comment from @Theo above.